# android emulator throwing error message Unfortunately, Helloworld has stopped

Tags: java, android, apache, connection, android-manifest

emulator throwing error message

> Unfortunately, Helloworld has stopped

**Debug Log information**

```
10-23 06:21:00.575: E/(5090): test 1
10-23 06:21:00.665: E/(5090): test 2
10-23 06:21:00.665: E/(5090): test 3
10-23 06:21:00.665: E/(5090):       main
10-23 06:21:00.686: E/(5090): ==[id=01, message=      main]
10-23 06:21:00.866: D/dalvikvm(5090): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 148K, 9% free 2870K/3136K, paused 37ms, total 50ms
10-23 06:21:00.918: D/AndroidRuntime(5090): Shutting down VM
10-23 06:21:00.918: W/dalvikvm(5090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-23 06:21:00.976: E/AndroidRuntime(5090):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myandroid.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

JAVA

```
        Log.e(TAG, "test 1");
       //log.debug("test 1");
       // output.setText("this is my tesing"+GroupAll);
        System.out.print("test");
        //check whether the msg empty or not
        if(GroupAll.length()>0) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.8.15:8085/mobile/save.php?device=system");
            Log.e(TAG, "test 2");
            try {Log.e(TAG, "test 3");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", GroupAll));
                   Log.e(TAG, GroupAll);
                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   Log.e(TAG, "=="+nameValuePairs);
                   httpclient.execute(httppost);
                   GroupAll = "";
                  // msgTextField.set.setText(""); //reset the message text field
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if i remove below snippet from manifest,

> 

**my error will be**

```
10-23 07:01:14.236: E/(8071): test 1
10-23 07:01:14.406: E/(8071): test 2
10-23 07:01:14.406: E/(8071): test 3
10-23 07:01:14.406: E/(8071):       main
10-23 07:01:14.455: E/(8071): ==[id=01, message=      main]
10-23 07:01:14.705: D/dalvikvm(8071): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 9% free 2866K/3136K, paused 37ms, total 52ms
10-23 07:01:14.726: W/System.err(8071): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.8.15:8085 refused
10-23 07:01:14.755: W/System.err(8071):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
10-23 07:01:14.755: W/System.err(8071):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
```

Comment: http calls have to be executed in a different thread from the UI Thread

Comment: what i have to do, should kill any thread or just reopen application is enough.

Comment: kill? why do you want to kill some poor thread. Look for the painless threading guide of android

Comment: @blackbelt what should i do now, to recover my code from pain.

Comment: from the stacktrace you missed the used internet permission in the manifest file. The next exception would be NetworkOnMainThreadExeception. What do you can do: 1. read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to your manifest

And use a different thread for http connections. Check for AsyncTask in order to do it. Anyway I'm not sure thats your only problem